# Extract a number from a filename

Tags: batch-file

Using Windows `CMD.exe` `.bat` files, is it possible to extract a number from the filename? So files named in this way:

`XYZ_789897897.txt`

The script should return `789897897`

Comment: Is it always the same number of digits and are they always at the end right before the extension?

Comment: Yes always same number and right at the end. Although, it would be good to make the length of digits variable.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840752/regex-in-batch-file 

You'll want to match Regex presumably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method"

```
@echo off
set FILENAME=XYZ_789897897.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in ("%filename%") do echo "%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Substrings can be done using `:~start,length` notation.

So if you have your file name in variable

`set FILENAME=XYZ_789897897.txt`

then you could do

`echo %FILENAME:~4,9%`

which extracts the string with length 9 starting at position 4.

This would only work for fixed number length and position in the file name though.